# Nested ASP.NET DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

Have run this by my entire dev group to no avail. Seems simple enough, here's the question.

I have a UserControl with a single, non-databound dropdownlist. The UserControl is then dropped onto the masterpage and then also loaded into an inheriting webform that has the control manually loaded onto the page.

No AJAX, straight post-back.

The issue I am running into is that the SelectedIndexChanged event is not firing for the second instance of the DropDownList. The first one fires just fine.

TIA

Here is the code for the ascx:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="SelectLanguage" autopostback="true" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
    <asp:listitem>- Select Language -</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem value="xxx">Netherlands</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem value="xxx">United Kingdom</asp:listitem>
    <asp:listitem value="xxx">United States</asp:listitem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

Here is the CB for the user control:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    SelectLanguage.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(SelectLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

protected void SelectLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Decided to pull the DropDowns out of the usercontrol and just drop them directly onto the masterpage and webform. Wired them both to the same event handler and seeing the same response. First instance fires, second one does not. These are two completely separate dropdown instances now mind you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly how this is, but the FancyBox lightbox jQuery library we're using to do the lightbox effect around the 2nd drop down is somehow messing with the bindings on the back end. No real time to figure out why, just let it be known it does in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the postback actually happen for the second dropdown, or does the page do nothing?

If the postback isn't happening, you have javascript errors on your page.

Comment: Postback happening both times. Event wires up oninit as well. Just doesn't fire.